# While loop in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my 1st Table

**Table1**:

```
    CatID   TenderNumber
    1        AA01012013
    2        AA01012013
    3        AA01012013
```

**Table2**:

```
SubCatID  CatID
1          1
2          1
3          2
4          2
5          2
6          3
```

So this is how my database looks like. Now I want to store `SubCatID` and `CatID` into new table using **C#**. These values will be retrieved from `TenderNumber` only as follows :

```
Select CatID from Table1 where TenderNumber='AA01012013'

while(SQLDataReader1.read())
{
         select SubCatID from Table2 where CatID=Reader1["CatID"]
         While(SQLDataReader2.read())
         {
              insert into Table3(SubCatID,CatID)Values(Reader2["SubCatID"],Reader1["CatID"])
         }
}
```

How can i do this using a stored procedure ?

Comment: I want to do this in C# using stored proc

Comment: @punter **why** do you want to do this in C#? or with a `while` loop? or even with a stored procedure? this is just a single 1-line set-based `insert` statement, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell This is just a sample of my actual requirement .

Comment: Can you give your actual requirement then? Giving a problem that can be trivially solved in a more straightforward fashion won't tend to produce useful answers for your actual requirement.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like

```
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT  t2.SubCatID,
        t2.CatID
FROm    Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
        Table2 t2   ON  t1.CatID = t2.CatID
WHERE   t1.TenderNumber='AA01012013'
```

Or even using a parameter, something like

```
DECLARE @TenderNumber VARCHAR(50) = 'AA01012013'

INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT  t2.SubCatID,
        t2.CatID
FROm    Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
        Table2 t2   ON  t1.CatID = t2.CatID
WHERE   t1.TenderNumber=@TenderNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure in your DB (for the body i've used the code from @astander :)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_InsertTenderInfo_byTenderNumber @TenderNumber VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table3
    SELECT  t2.SubCatID,
            t2.CatID
    FROm    Table1 t1 INNER JOIN
            Table2 t2   ON  t1.CatID = t2.CatID
    WHERE   t1.TenderNumber=@TenderNumber
END
```

And in your c# code:

```
using (var conection = new SqlConnection("conString"))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        command.Connection = conection;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "dbo.p_InsertTenderInfo_byTenderNumber";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TenderNumber", "AA01012013"));
        conection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conection.Close();
    }
}
```